# How to create a relationship of two objects, where both objects hold eachother's reference?

Tags: c#

Rewrite of the question.

Basically I have these two classes:

```
class Show {
 public List<Episode> Episodes{ get; set; }
}

class Episode {
 public Show Show{ get; set; }
}
```

When I add an episode to a show, I'll have to create a new episode object. However, when I do that, I'll also have to fill in the show and it turns into a circular problem. How can I add an episode to a show where the episode also holds a reference to the show it's part of, without ending up in an eternal circle?

I think I've left out some important info:

I have a factory which creates viewmodels for me. When I want a list of shows, call the method `CreateShowViewModel` on each show in the list. This method is as follows:

```
    public ShowViewModel CreateShowViewModel(Show show) {
        return new ShowViewModel {
            ShowID = show.ShowID,
            Title = show.Title,
            Episodes = CreateEpisodeViewModels(show.Episodes)
        };
    }
```

When it has to instantiate the episodes, it calls a method which performs the following function on every episode:

```
    public EpisodeViewModel CreateEpisodeViewModel(Episode episode) {
        return new EpisodeViewModel {
            ShowID = episode.ShowID,
            EpisodeID = episode.EpisodeID,
            Title = episode.Title,
            Show = CreateShowViewModel(episode.Show)
        };
    }
```

which will create the show again, etc. This poses as a circular reference, no?

Comment: According to the statistics shown to me, it has been 1 hour, and 27 views of your "question". There has been no comments and no answers. All of this tells me that your question is not clear. To begin with, what is your *actual* question. Can you summarize it into 1 sentence? The next problem with your question is that you've dumped a lot of code that is only part of a larger solution, so nobody is actually able to run your code without a lot of the rest of the code. Can you post a short and complete piece of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have removed a million lines and rewritten it way easier. No idea why I ever wrote it that hard. Should I repost this if it doesn't get any more views/comments? I'm not sure if people will still find this 3-4 hours later.

Comment: Create a show with no episodes. Create an episode and set its show to the show you just created. Add the episode to the show. Not sure how this was so complicated.

Comment: I have edited the question with additional info. Does this change anything? (the VS test engine crashes when I perform my test with this code, so I'm guessing something's wrong).

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `CreateShowViewModel` and `CreateEpisodeViewModel` like that. Rather, let them take an (optional?) parameter, like `CreateEpisodeViewModel(Episode episode, ShowViewModel show)`. Or you can get fancy with a `ConditionalWeakTable` to ensure you only ever create 1 `*ViewModel` per `Show`/`Episode`.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks, I'll use the first option and read up on the table! If you repost it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it and mark this solved.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a `Show` (or Series) with `Episodes` and for some reason you want a reference to the parent from the child (Episode->Show). That's fine, but there's no reason to display that in the ViewModel as it seems like a model behavior. Remove the `Show = CreateShowViewModel(...)` line and your problem goes away.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two apparent solutions to this problem. The first one is simply to pass along an optional ViewModel, so you break the circle in the method-calls. Something like this:

```
    public ShowViewModel CreateShowViewModel(Show show, List<EpisodeViewModel> episodes = null /* guessing type */) {
        var viewModel = new ShowViewModel {
            ShowID = show.ShowID,
            Title = show.Title
        };
        viewModel.Episodes = episodes ?? CreateEpisodeViewModels(show.Episodes, viewModel);
        return viewModel;
    }

    public EpisodeViewModel CreateEpisodeViewModel(Episode episode, ShowViewModel show = null) {
        var viewModel = new EpisodeViewModel {
            ShowID = episode.ShowID,
            EpisodeID = episode.EpisodeID,
            Title = episode.Title
        };
        viewModel.Show = show ?? CreateShowViewModel(episode.Show, viewModel); // this might cause a problem due to the fact that you only have 1 episode, and not all of them.
        return viewModel;
    }
```

The other way would be to add some cashing from `Show`->`ShowViewModel` and `Episode`->`EpisodeViewModel`. I recommend using a `ConditionalWeakTable` for this.

Something along the lines of this:

```
static ConditionalWeakTable<Show, ShowViewModel> _shows = new ConditionalWeakTable<Show, ShowViewModel>();
static ShowViewModel GetForShow(Show show)
{
     return _shows.GetValue(show, s => CreateShowViewModel(s));
} // do the same for episode.
```

Comment: I'm ok with errors beeing fixed, and code beeing cleaned slightly, but please make sure you are at the last update before submitting... The code reverted to before I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, I'm going away now, there's too many people editing on my post the same time as me o.O

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I just wanted to fix the `to > two` but seems some one went in at the same time, apologize.

Comment: I had a few issues with the conditionalweaktable which I'll look into once I've read more about it. Thanks for pointing me towards this though! I have fixed the problem by breaking the inner circle with the first method. Thanks for input!

Comment: @Prix don't worry about it. Problem was, I was fixing the same thing ^^, and so was another guy, at the same time -.- And also, I updated the code (which the other guy didn't notice, so when he updated it got reverted), so I reverted, and figured I'd fix the `to > two`, but then there were you ^^. I feel like I'm getting way more attention than I should have xD